# weird behavior of tikz with arrow tip in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
 markings,
 mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->-] (3,3) to (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to picture a diagonal segment with arrow in the middle: why does the above result in just the line, with no arrow at all?

Note that if I slightly move the points, so that it approaches horizontality, the arrow gradually starts to appear

Comment: It works for me. May be you need an update.

Comment: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Comment: @HarishKumar even with the update, the command pdflatex on the above tex file does *not* produce the desired arrow; does it work for you?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'm now with tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 D.E. Knuth...

Comment: This was due to an issue with the OP's PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The above code compiles fine with pdflatex on my linux box. You may try to update by running 
**tlmgr update --all**
as root.

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't help; when you say it compiles fine, do you mean you also see the arrow or just the line?

Comment: OK, let me close this: the arrow is there, but my pdf viewer does not visualize it at all below a certain zoom level. very weird